# Using a listbox to display a list across different classes

Tags: c#, list, winforms

I have implemented a list system which records the users name, the total amount of points which they have scores and the amount of time it took to do this. Im now having problems with trying to display the list "players" from another class. So within my HighScoresMenu form when trying to display the content of the players list within a the list box, the list box only displays "Game.Player".

Is there any possible solutions to this issue. Any Help would be appreciated.

```
public partial class MainMenu : Form
{

   public static List<Player> GetPlayers(float newScore, float newPoints, 
   string PlayersName)
   {
       var players = new List<Player>();
       var newPlayer = new Player
       {
           Name = PlayersName,
           Points = newPoints,
           Timer = newScore
       };
       players.Add(newPlayer);

       var TopTenLevel1 = players.OrderByDescending(x => x.Timer).Take(10);
       return players;
   }
}

public partial class HighScoresMenu : Form
{
    foreach (var players in MainMenu.GetPlayers(newScore, newPoints, 
    PlayersName))
    {
        ListBoxLevel1.Items.Add(players);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to tell the listbox which fields in the Player class to read from and use for displaying, it can't guess

Comment: I don't know how to solve your problem, but you don't need to order and create a list in this case because you are always creating only one object. You could return just the object filled and remove the "foreach".

Comment: I believe the syntax is wrong, your foreach loop is ambient in the class. Shouldn't  it  be in a method? or is it assumed?

Comment: Either set [DisplayMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) on your ListBox, or override [ToString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-7.0) for your `Player` class to control how it looks as an entry in the ListBox.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also few years ago: The function GetPlayers is static, that means that the content (value) or the variable isn't accessible from other classes.

You need to remove 'static' and initiate the MainMenu in the HighScoresMenu class like this:

```
//MainMenu
public static List<Player> GetPlayers(float newScore, float newPoints, string PlayersName)

//HighScoreMenu
MainMenu main = new MainMenu(); 
menu.GetPlayers(newScore, newPoints, PlayersName);
```

I hope this will fix the problem (removing keyword 'static' from the function and initiating the MainMenu class)
I would glad to hear if the current situation is solved or not. :) I hope I did remember it good.

### Edit

After I took a second look you are foreach looping it as var player.
But loop it as Player player. Because you putted in in the other class as Player object inside a list of Players. Now you are retrieving it as a var.**

So the final conclusion:

```
    public partial class HighScoresMenu : Form
{
    foreach (Player players in MainMenu.GetPlayers(newScore, newPoints, 
    PlayersName))
    {
        ListBoxLevel1.Items.Add(players.getName());
    }
}
```

I am curious let me know :D

### Edit 2

Also letting you know in case of you never know. You are always making just one Player so there isn't actually a list needed and this piece of code:

```
var TopTenLevel1 = players.OrderByDescending(x => x.Timer).Take(10);
```

This will order it but you aren't doing anything with it (var 'TopTenLevel1'). Just letting you know :) You could save the ordered list by returning it (overwriting variable also possible).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so to begin, I might not understand your question correctly. What I get from it is that your list view is displaying the name of the object, hence the "Game.Player". So you would have to change the following:

`ListBoxLevel1.Items.Add(players);`

to something like the following:

`ListBoxLevel1.Items.Add($"Player: {players.Name}, Score: {players.Points}");`

I'm not sure what your list box is taking as a parameter in the `Items.Add();` method, so this answer is assuming it's a string.